# Youtube API returns wrong value

Tags: youtube-api

This is a part of my code:

```
$key = 'XXX';

function check_video($id, $url) {
    $x = get_data('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id='.$url.'&key='.$key);
    $x = json_decode($x, true);

    if($x['items'][0]['status']['embeddable'] == true){
        echo "$id = TRUE --- ";
    }else{
        echo "$id = FALSE --- ";
    }
}
check_video(1, '9bZkp7q19f0');
```

The function should check if the video is embeddable and then simply echo true or false but it keeps printing "1 = FALSE --- " even though a video is embeddable.

Example of video: http://i.gyazo.com/7a84e78cc665ca4920cef18e341f09b6.png

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code above the variable $key in function check_video() is undefined. The variable $key  has to be defined in the function or passed in. If it's just a simple copy/paste snafu then continue:

I don't see the definition for function get_code() so I'll assume it's a simple cURL wrapper.

Second, put the finished url into your browser and see if it works.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=status&id=9bZkp7q19f0&key=YOUR_KEY

Third, put a print_r($x) after json_decode() to see if the YouTube API is returning an error because of something in the get_code() function (like a timeout). You should check for an error regardless.

For me it worked fine.